# How to fix 'continuous value supplied to discrete scale' in with scale_color_brewer

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, colorbrewer

I am attempting to make a map of global data anomaly (precip, temp etc) and need to use a diverging color palette. I have code that runs well with `scale_color_viridis` but it does not easily convert with `scale_color_brewer`. I would like to use the `RdBu` diverging palette.

I have tried supplying the values `vars` within the function `scale_color_brewer` and using `scale_fill` brewer but I would like to continue plotting using the `geom_points` I have so far.

```
  titletext <- paste(VAR, "Response")
  expand.grid(lon, lat) %>%
    rename(lon = Var1, lat = Var2) %>%
    mutate(lon = ifelse(lon > 180, -(360 - lon), lon),
           vars = as.vector(global.array)) %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = vars),
               size = 2.0) + 
    borders("world", colour="black", fill=NA) + 
    scale_color_brewer(type="div", palette="RdBu")+
    #scale_color_viridis(na.value="white",name = VAR) +  
    theme(legend.direction="vertical", legend.position="right", 
          legend.key.width=unit(0.4,"cm"), legend.key.heigh=unit(2,"cm")) + 
    coord_quickmap() + ggtitle(titletext)
```

Error message is

> Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale

and

> Warning messages:
>   1: In RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n, pal) :
>     n too large, allowed maximum for palette RdBu is 11
>   Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors

Answer (score 7):

You can bin/coarse-grain the continuous values to give them a discrete-ordered value to map to the discrete 8 to 12 colors included in your Brewer palette of choice.

But I think the solution you are looking for is to "distill" them with the `scale_color_distiller()` or `scale_fill_distiller()` functions already included in ggplot2, effectively converting them to a continuous color scale. Documentation and examples are provided in some canonical locations:

- https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html
- https://ggplot2-book.org/scale-colour.html#colour-continuous

Comment: Yep, `scale_*_distiller()` is what you want.

Answer (score -2):

`RdBu` is a discrete color palette, but you are trying to use it for continuous data.

Please see [this documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html) and use `scale_colour_gradient()` instead.